# Lattice of subcategories: subobject classifier in Cat

Tags: ct.category-theory, topos-theory, lattices, ra.rings-and-algebras

Two short questions:

- Is there any work classifying the lattice of subcategories of an arbitrary (sufficiently small) category $\mathcal{C}$, similar to the way that the set of subsets of set $\mathcal{S}$ is isomorphic to the functions $\mathcal{S}\to\mathbf{2}$, where $\mathbf{2}$ is a two point set?
- Is there standard notation denoting the lattice of subcategories of some category?

The definitions found in [nLab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/subcategory) are phrased in terms of functors going into $\mathcal{C}$, but the definition for sets talks about functions out of the set $\mathcal{S}$. Why are things done differently? That is, rather than characterising subcategories in terms of functors into $\mathcal{C}$, why not characterise them in terms of functors out of $\mathcal{C}$? Something like:

> The lattice of subcategories of $\mathcal{C}$ is isomorphic to the functor category $\mathcal{SO}^\mathcal{C}$, for some "subobject classifier" $\mathcal{SO}$.

Comment: If you have the good fortune to have a theorem like Birkhoff's HSP theorem, your lattice will be dual to some lattice of something like equational theories are for varieties.  Is there even a Galois correspondence between the categories and something else that gives you a similar lattice to study?  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2010.06.19

Comment: Be careful.  The notion of "subcategory" is deeply problematic.  See the nLab page at http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/subcategory

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In his comment on Finn Lawler's response, Mike Shulman points out that Cat has no subobject classifier in the 2-categorical sense.  It also fails to have a subobject classifier in the 1-categorical sense.  To see this, note that if Cat had a subobject classifier, then it would be a topos, as it is cartesian closed.  However, Cat is not a topos since, e.g., it is not locally cartesian closed (cf. Johnstone's "Elephant", A1.5).

Answer (score 3):

Remember that $\mathbf{2}$ is (classically) the *subobject classifier* in Set, so that there is a natural bijection $\mathrm{Sub}(X) \cong \hom(X,\mathbf{2})$ given by pulling back along $\mathrm{true} \colon \mathbf{1} \hookrightarrow \mathbf{2}$.  So you can think of a subset of X as either an isomorphism class of monos into X or a function $X \to \mathbf{2}$.

Mike Shulman's pages about [2-toposes](http://ncatlab.org/michaelshulman/show/What+is+a+2-topos) say that there is *no* subobject classifier in Cat.  I don't know of a reference, but you could drop a query box there asking.  Such a thing would classify functors that are faithful and injective on objects (i.e. the monos in Cat).

**Edit**:  I misinterpreted Mike's remark at loc. cit., but see Michael Warren's answer.

The closest thing I know of (see loc. cit.) is to classify discrete opfibrations with an equivalence between functors $A \to \mathrm{Set}$ and discrete opfibrations over A, given by pullback along the forgetful functor $\mathrm{Set}_\bullet \to \mathrm{Set}$ out of the category of pointed sets (see [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/generalized+universal+bundle)).

These don't look very similar, but in fact the Cat example is related to the comprehensive factorization system (initial, discrete opfibration) in Cat (see Street--Walters, *The comprehensive factorization of a functor*, Bull. AMS, (5)79, 1973), while the corresponding system in Set is (epi, mono).  The latter also arises as the image factorization system, while in Cat, as far as I can tell, the two notions don't coincide.

Comment: What I meant on that page is that the *2-category* Cat has no subobject classifier which classifies its 2-categorical subobjects (probably meaning fully faithful functors) 2-categorically, i.e. in terms of hom-categories rather than homsets.  I'm not sure if the 1-category Cat has a subobject classifier in the 1-categorical sense.


Comment: Oh, OK.  My mistake.  But as Michael Warren points out, if Cat had a subobject classifier then it would be a topos and so locally cartesian closed, but it isn't so it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Special cases being the submonoids of a monoid, and suborders of a partial order. What would one expect to be a common generalisation of those two, that was of interest? All one really asks for is a closure condition on morphisms (modulo talk about identity maps).

Comment: So, for the case where the "subcategories" are "ordered by inclusion" then asking if it is a lattice makes sense.  But otherwise ... ???
